# Jquery mouseenter question

Tags: jquery

I am a beginner with jquery.
I have n divs which if i hover above them another div will fadein.
Like this:

```
    $(".res2").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#jucInfores2").fadeIn("normal");
    });
    $(".res3").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#jucInfores3").fadeIn("normal");
    });
    $(".res4").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#jucInfores4").fadeIn("normal");
    });
    $(".res5").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#jucInfores5").fadeIn("normal");
    });
    $(".res6").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#jucInfores6").fadeIn("normal");
    });
    $(".res7").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#jucInfores7").fadeIn("normal");
    });
    $(".scl").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#jucInfoscl").fadeIn("normal");
    });
    $(".scc").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#jucInfoscc").fadeIn("normal");
    });
    $(".scr").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#jucInfoscr").fadeIn("normal");
    });
    $(".ml").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#jucInfoml").fadeIn("normal");
    });
    $(".mcl").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#jucInfomcl").fadeIn("normal");
    });
```

Is there another way to do this for me not to repeat so many times the code?
If i have 20 such divs for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you invert the logic and match the `#jucInfo` elements instead, then use the variable part of their ids to build the class selectors:

```
$("[id^='jucInfo']").each(function() {
    var $info = $(this);
    $("." + this.id.substr(7)).mouseenter(function() {
        $info.fadeIn("normal");
    });
});
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. In the first line the quotes needed to be exchanged to work. "[id^='jucInfo']"  needed to be changed to '[id^="jucInfo"]'

Comment: @hhh3112, actually, they don't. The quotes inside the attribute selector are even optional in this case. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ddrS/).

Comment: I am a beginner so you must be right. The code above didn't work on my page, but when I changed the quotes it worked. Great answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to wrap the main code in a Javascript function (very literal example for readability):

```
function jucInfo(res, infores) {
    $(res).mouseenter(function () {
        $(infores).fadeIn("normal");
    });
}
```

to which you can pass all your variables when you call the function:

```
jucInfo(".res2", "#jucInfores2");
jucInfo(".res3", "#jucInfores3");
...
```

To refine this further, place all your selector classes and ID pairs in a [hash](http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html), then make a loop that repeats the above the required number of times (i.e. the number of elements in the hash).